# Applying univariate coxph function to multiple covariates

Tags: r, cox-regression

For my data set columns, I have Time, Status, Treatment, Gender, BMI. I am trying to apply the univariate coxph function with the covariates Treatment, Gender and BMI.

This is my code:

```
univ_models <- lapply( univ_formulas, function(x){coxph(x, data = RemissionTimes)})
univ_results <- lapply(univ_models,
                       function(x){ 
                           x <- summary(x)
                           p.value<-signif(x$wald["pvalue"], digits=2)
                           wald.test<-signif(x$wald["test"], digits=2)
                           beta<-signif(x$coef[1], digits=2);#coeficient beta
                           HR <-signif(x$coef[2], digits=2);#exp(beta)
                           HR.confint.lower <- signif(x$conf.int[,"lower .95"], 2)
                           HR.confint.upper <- signif(x$conf.int[,"upper .95"],2)
                           HR <- paste0(HR, " (", 
                                        HR.confint.lower, "-", HR.confint.upper, ")")
                           res<-c(beta, HR, wald.test, p.value)
                           names(res)<-c("beta", "HR (95% CI for HR)", "wald.test", 
                                         "p.value")
                           return(res)
                           #return(exp(cbind(coef(x),confint(x))))
                       })
res <- t(as.data.frame(univ_results, check.names = FALSE))
as.data.frame(res)
```

However, I get this when I run it:

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 4
> as.data.frame(res)
Error in as.data.frame(res) : object 'res' not found
```

I am not sure how to fix it. I can't see where rows differ, and I don't understand why R is not finding res.

Answer (score 0):

Does the object res appear in the preceding codes? You could also check whether they are blank spaces in your table. I don't know whether this will assist you.

Comment: res doesn't appear before in my code and there are 0's in my data set but not blanks. Nay more help I would appreciate.

Comment: In my data set I have a column with A, B, C. These are factored, but this adds more more row into Treatment. How do I remove this extra row?

Comment: To your first question, I think 0 can still be included in survival data. You said res doesnt appear in the code before. Try fitting it this way:

Comment: > #Univariate Cox analyses can be computed as follow:#
> res.cox <- coxph(Surv(Time, Status) ~ Treatment + Gender + BMI , data =  RemmisionTimes)
> res.cox

Comment: Then follow it up with the code you posted. As for columns, I am not sure whether I got you clearly